# Происхождение слова "витязь"

Tags: этимология

Искала по форуму, но не нашла такого вопроса. Интересно, какое происхождение у слова "витязь"? Это русское слово?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Слово "витязь" происходит от праслав.
> формы *vitę,ʒь, от которой в числе
> прочего произошли: укр. ви́тязь,
> др.-русск. витязь, болг. ви́тез,
> сербохорв. ви̏те̑з,
> сербск.-церк.-слав. витѩѕ|?|ь,
> словенск. vȋtez, чешск. vítěz,
> словацк. vít’az, польск. zwyciężyć
> «победить», в.-луж. wićaz «герой»,
> «крестьянин, арендатор». Следует также
> обратить внимание на ср.-в.-нем.
> Witseze «rustici» (с XI в.) и ср.-лат.
> withasii «вид наследного воинского
> сословия всадников у гломачей в
> Мейсении». Др.-прусск. witing (с 1299
> г.) «служилое дворянство»
> предположительно заимств. из польск.
> Слав.* vitę,ʒь, несомненно, заимств.
> из герм. *víking-, др.-исл. víkingr.
> Стар.* vicęʒь могло дать в результате
> диссимиляции *vitęʒь (ср. ц в
> це́рковь, цата и др.). Англос. víking
> известно начиная с VIII в.;
> засвидетельствовано также фриз.
> witsing. Труднее определить путь
> заимствования. Сканд. этимология не
> объясняет распространения слова в
> сербохорв., а также -dzь при наличии
> варя́г, колбя́г, буря́г. Указывают на
> тождество англос. Wicingas с эрулами,
> которые предпринимали набеги начиная с
> III в. и лишь в VI в. были оттеснены
> датчанами. Наряду с этим возможно
> предположение, что слав. слово было
> распространено лангобардами или
> варнами. Герм. слово связано с
> др.-сакс. wîk «жилье», др.-в.-нем.
> wîch — то же. Согласно Бьёркману,
> местом его первого появления был Litus
> Saxonum «Саксонский берег». Оно
> древнее эпохи викингов в собственном
> смысле слова. Рум. viteaz заимств. из
> слав., но не из укр. ввиду i (на месте
> у). Неубедительно объяснение слав.
> vit|e,ʒjr'| из др.-исл. hvítingr
> «светловолосый, знатный», которое
> сближается с англос. Wîtland «западная
> Самбия». Оно не учитывает
> распространения слова в в.-луж.,
> сербохорв. и в Мекленбурге; ср. фам.
> Vitense.

Answer (score 0):

Витязь - витающий Ас - живущий Бог, аналогично слову Князь - Кон Ас - Бог в Коне - Бог ограниченного пространства.

Comment: — Интересно, какое происхождение у слова "витязь"? Это русское слово? — такой был вопрос. О витязе. Причём же тут князья, кони, асы?